# Creating files in specific path with python

Tags: python, file, path, new-operator, sys

is it possible to create a file with a specific extension, name and python with the sys module or any other module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with the path and the file name:

```
import os

PATH = '/home/user/somepath'
FILE = 'somefile.someext'

os.makedirs( PATH, exist_ok=True)   # create the PATH if not exists

full_name = os.path.join( PATH, FILE )
with open( full_name ) as fout :
    print >>fout, 'some message'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
f = open('myfile.myextension', 'w')
f.write('hello')
f.close()
```

You can create file with any extension you would like. If you want another software to read it, for example, if you want to create an excel file (xlsx) or pdf you might need additional packages.

Comment: and add `f.close()` at the end, to not being crash.